# Display text in nav-bar on the right hand side

Tags: javascript, angular, bootstrap-4

I am trying to display text in the nav bar on the right hand side. All examples I have seen are using bootstrap like below:

```
<nav class="admin-nav navbar navbar-expand navbar-light">
    <div class="container text-right">Test
        <p >Some text</p>
    </div>
</nav>
```

`Some text` is displayed to the right only if I add `Test` text to the `div` element - if I don't `Some text` is displayed on the left side of the nav-bar.
How can I have just one text displayed on the rigth side of the nav bar?

Answer (score 1):

You can use flex layout(instead of the text-right). Try this :

```
<nav class="admin-nav navbar navbar-expand navbar-light">
<div class="container d-flex justify-content-end">
    <div style="margin-right:10px">Some text</div>
    <div >Some other  text</div>
</div>
</nav>
```